# how to apply filter function to items in multiple list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I wanna get values from multiple(?) list, **which is not 0**(I think `filter` can be one of solutions).

list as below:

```
>>ls = [[i for i in np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)] for _ in range(7)]
>>ls
>>
[[2, 3, 3, 0, 0],
 [4, 2, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
 [3, 4, 4, 4, 3],
 [3, 4, 3, 3, 2]]
```

**Expected result** is:

```
[2,3,3,4,2,4,3,2,1,2,4,2,4,2,3,4,3,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,3,2]
```

I tried using **`filter` function**, wanted expand this idea, but I failed:

```
>> [elem for elem in filter(lambda x: x if x != 0 else False, ls[0])]
>> 
[2, 3, 3]
```

I wanna find fastest way to get expected result, not using `for loop`.
Would you suggest any good idea?

**Edit:**

Oops, Sorry for confusing you.
I saying 'not usting for loop' means, I wanna use list comprehension instead of `for loop`, because I heard list comprehension fater than `for loop`.

Comment: "not using `for loop`" - is there a reason for this? A requirement of the (homework) exercise? Explicit for loops are often **not** what you need to optimize.

Comment: `sum([[i for i in np.random.randint(0, 5, 5) if i] for _ in range(7)], [])` ...

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I heard list comprehension faster than for loop, and I wanna use this on for my coding test I working on now :)

Comment: Looks like you're using `numpy` to generate the nested list. Why not use numpy's `np.nonzero`? Check my soln

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Not just a duplicate, but the original also has timetests you can look at if you want speed.

Comment: @zwer Wow Cool!! Thank~

Comment: @Mars I see, I missed the keyword, `make flat list`. I just checked the link and think it is definitely great answer, but I wanted to know how to apply `filter` func. to my problem. Thanks for your great link.

Comment: If you wanted to apply filter, first you make the list flat, *then* you filter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
[j for i in ls for j in i if j != 0]
```

---

```
ls = [[i for i in np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)] for _ in range(7)]

[[1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 4],
 [2, 0, 3, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 0],
 [2, 4, 1, 1, 2]]

[j for i in ls for j in i if j != 0]
# [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```

---

If you want to avoid any *explicit* looping here's an option using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and `filter`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, chain(*ls)))
# [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```

---

Looks like you're also using NumPy for creating the list. Note that this would be way simpler and more efficient using [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, (7,5))
a[np.nonzero(a)]
# [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @yatu's answer, since it's `0`, you can just do `if x`:

```
print([x for i in ls for x in i if x])
```

Or without loop:

```
print(np.array(ls).flatten()[np.array(ls).flatten() != 0].tolist())
```

Both output:

```
[1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```